# Turning off random PHP gif logo

Tags: php

How does one go about turning off my PHP site from displaying the php logo gif when accessing: `sitename.com/?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42`

After some reading and hunting I came across this:

> PHP CODER GUY WITH BREADSTICKS (Thies
>   C. Arntzen): PHP Version 4.0.0 - 4.2.3
>
> BROWN DOG IN GRASS (Stig's dog,
>   Nadia): PHP Version 4.3.0 - 4.3.10
>
> BLACK SCOTTISH TERRIER (Zeev's dog,
>   Scotch): PHP Versions 4.3.11 - 4.4.6;
>   and 5.0.4 - 5.1.2
>
> BUNNY (Sterling's rabbit, Carmella):
>   PHP Version 5.0.0 - 5.0.3
>
> COLORED PHP LOGO: PHP Version 5.1.3 -
>   5.2.13
>
> ELEPHANT PHP LOGO: PHP Version 5.3.0 -
>   current

Turns out the images change for every version.

Anyway, is there a way to turn this off in the PHP .ini ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a relatively simple fix.

In the `php.ini` there is an option called `expose_php` which must be set to off!